# Difference “net start” behavior in Win 7 and 8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

I set a service to manual start. To run the service I use the command "net start service".

After reboot, Win 7 will no longer run the service until I do the net start again. But Win 8 will still run the service after reboot.

What "net start" command available in Win 8 so that the service will not run after reboot like Win 7?